# Retrieves value from Wpf UserControlLibrary to WpfForm

Tags: wpf, user-interface, controls

In my WPF application, I have a usercontrol library. In this library, I have a `listview` control along with `textbox` and `button` controls.

I have placed this usercontrol in a WPF window form. How can I retrieve the `listviewitems` of my usercontrol in this WPF window form?

Answer (score 0):

You ask a very general question. There are dozens of ways to do that, depends on your needs. For example: when you place you UserControl within the Window - you should name it (e.g. . Then, within the UserControl, you can have a public function, or a public getter, which will return the items (it is the 'Items' property of the ListView).
Another way is binding. If you have a ViewModel, or any other class as the DataContext, you can bind the ItemsSource of the ListView to a collection on your ViewModel. Unless you change the DataContext of the UserControl - it will have the same DataContext as the main Window.